# C# DateTime.Now not writing correct time to MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# program that communicates with MySql database and I want to write current time to database column defined as TIME. Now, when I run my program the time that has been written is for example 00:00:19 and not for example 19:34:00. Why this happens and how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION**

This solved the problem:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Comment: We need to see your code to know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this because the format mysql :  `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`

check the format in you programme or try to insert a String like this `"2016-23-08 13:00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem caused by *dateTimeVariable.ToString()* method of your *DateTime* value.

To solve this problem use *dateTimeVariable.ToString("s")* to convert the DateTime to standard *DateTime* string.